# Issue with Django foreign key assignment

Tags: python, django

I have a series of related models. Country -> League -> Team -> Player. The model works fine relating country to league and league to team, but the team id is different as teams play in more than one competition. To deal with this I've added a ref column with an id for each team. I would like to use this ref column as the Foreign Key in my player model but I'm getting errors when I try to parse the data to the Postgres database.

I've tried using to_field and unique=True but still end up with an error. I've taken a look around but haven't found a solution yet.

Here is my models code:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime


class Country(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="TBA")
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,default=0)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name

class League(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="TBA")
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,default=0)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name


class Team(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="TBA")
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,default=0)          
    league = models.ForeignKey(League,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name

class Player(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64,default="Unknown")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64,default="Unknown")
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=64,default="Unknown")
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default = datetime.date.today)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="Unknown")
    team_ref =models.ForeignKey(Team,to_field="ref",on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, I think you model design is bit wrong. You should make Team to League relation as [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) Field. So that, a Team can be assigned to multiple Leagues. If you want to maintain different Squads for different Tournaments, then you should create a new Model Named `Squads` and use it as [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through), and make a many to many relation to that Squads Model from Player. For example:

```
class Team(models.Model):
   # other fields

   league = models.ManyToManyField(League, through="Squad")

class Squad(models.Model):
   team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
   league = models.ForeignKey(League)


class Player(models.Model):
   squad = models.ManyToManyField(Squad)
```

Comment: Life saver. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!